# How to mock AMQP consumers in Camel testing?

Tags: java, testing, mocking, apache-camel

Say I have the following route:

```
from(rabbitMQUri)
    .to(myCustomerProcessor)
    .choice()
        .when(shouldGotoA)
            .to(fizz)
        .when(shouldGotoB)
            .to(buzz)
        .otherwise()
            .to(foo);
```

Let's pretend that `myCustomProcessor` tunes `shouldGotoA` and `shouldGotoB` according to the message consumed from RabbitMQ.

I would like to unit test 3 scenarios:

1. A "*fizz*" message is consumed and `shouldGotoA` is set to true, which executes the first `when(...)`.
2. A "*buzz*" message is consumed and `shouldGotoB` is set to true, which executes the second `when(...)`.
3. A "*foo*" message is consumed and the `otherwise()` is executed.

My question is: how do I mock/stub the RabbitMQ endpoint so that the route executes as it normally will in production, but so that I don't have to actually connect the test to a RabbitMQ server? I need some kind of "mock message" producer.

A code example or snippet would be *extremely helpful* and very much so appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one way of putting together a suitable test.

Firstly define an empty Camel Context with just a ProducerTemplate in it:

```
<camel:camelContext id="camelContext">
   <camel:template id="producerTemplate" />
</camel:camelContext>
```

I do this so that when I execute the test, I can control which routes actually start as I don't want all my routes starting during a test.

Now in the test class itself, you'll need references to the producer template and Camel Context. In my case, I'm using Spring and I autowire them in:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/spring/spring-test-camel.xml" })
public class MyTest {

    @Autowired
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext;
```

In the test itself, replace the RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ/JMS component in the context with the seda or direct component. eg replace all JMS calls with a seda queue.

```
camelContext.removeComponent("jms");
camelContext.addComponent("jms", this.camelContext.getComponent("seda"));
camelContext.addRoutes(this.documentBatchRouting);
```

Now whenever you are reading or writing to a JMS URI, it is actually going to a seda queue. This is similar to injecting a new URI into the component but take less configuration and allows you to add new endpoints to the route without worrying about remembering to inject all the URIs.

Finally in the test, use the the producer template to send a test message:

```
producerTemplate.sendBody("jms:MyQueue", 2);
```

You're route should then execute and you can test your expectations.

Two things to note are:

1. Your transaction boundaries may change, especially if you replace JMS queues with a direct component
2. If you are testing several routes, you'll have to be careful to remove the route from the Camel Context at the end of the tests for that route.

Comment: Thanks @matt helliwell (+1) - I'll check this out when I get home tonight and will post back here with feedback! One quick followup question in the meantime: when you say that my "*transaction boundaries may change*", what exactly do you mean? Can you give a specific example? Remember I'm using AMQP/RabbitMQ for my actual messaging (in production routes). Thanks again!

Comment: One case is if you are doing DB updates in your classes being tested and are relying on the test case to roll back the transaction. If you have a seda/jms queue then the transaction created in your test case will not propagate to the classes under test so you can't roll back any DB updates they did. It would work fine if you used a direct component. Similarly if you replace a jms queue with a "direct:" component in your route, you then get any transactions propagating across the "direct:" component.

Comment: what is camelContext.addRoutes(this.documentBatchRouting);?

Comment: I tried this with rabbitmq and the components do not get removed. Once you add the route it tries to connect to rabbitmq rather than to seda.

Comment: It seems to only work for endpoints which can accept same parameters. SEDA does not accept all parameters that apply to rabbit so fails when you replace it.

Answer (score 5):

It may depend what component you are using (AMQP or RabbitMQ) for the communication.

The **single most important** resource for sample code in Camel is the junit test cases in the source.

Two files that does similar things to what you need are these two, but you may want to look around in the test cases in general to get inspiration:
[AMQPRouteTest.java](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-amqp/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/amqp/AMQPRouteTest.java)
[RabbitMQConsumerIntTest.java](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQConsumerIntTest.java)

A more "basic" way to make routes testable is to make the "from" uri a parameter.
Let's say you make your RouteBuilder something like this:

```
   private String fromURI = "amqp:/..";

   public void setFromURI(String fromURI){
     this.fromURI = fromURI;
   }

   public void configure(){
     from(fromURI).whatever();
   }
```

Then you can inject a "seda:foobar" endpoint in the fromURI before your start the unit test. The [seda](http://camel.apache.org/seda) endpoint is [trivial to test](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/seda/SedaQueueTest.java). This assumes you don't need to test AMQP/RabbitMQ specific constructs, but simply receive the payload.

Comment: Thanks @Petter (+1) but I was worried someone would just give me a "you should inject the String URI"-type answer... I need whatever is mocked/stubbed in the `from(...)` to actually generate messages that will be routed correctly. I do not believe injecting it with `seda:foo` will do this for me...any ideas? Thanks again!

Comment: Hmm.. the uri inject was my second option (sometimes it's good enough). Look at the two linked .java files from AMQ source for more proper mock

Comment: To actually produce messages, just use a ProducerTemplate in your test code (http://camel.apache.org/producertemplate.html). Also bear in mind that your transactional behaviour may change if you replace RibbitMQ with a SEDA or direct endpoint.

Comment: Thanks @matthelliwell (+1) - but think about it: if I add a `ProducerTemplate`, how would I inject it instead of the RabbitMQ endpoint?

Comment: It'll be easier to explain if I can dig out some sample code but I won't be able to do that until during the week. Basically you override the URI in your test class. You also define the producer template in your test class. When you run your test, the test case calls the producer template to send a message to the URI you've defined. This then gets picked up and processed by your route.

Comment: There are sample test classes for AMQP routes as well as RabbitMQ routes from Camel itself linked to in my answer. They do test complete routes with "from" etc. Please read them.

Comment: Thanks @Petter (+1) - specifically I'm looking at [this example](https://fisheye6.atlassian.com/browse/camel-git/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQConsumerIntTest.java?r=8a74fc9fcb71c12ba65291dee1a9a5ff1103cc0a) from your link above. However I'm not seeing the connection between `createRouteBuilder` and the running test. How/when/where is the route (being tested) actually created?

Comment: Looking at `createRouteBuilder` you will see that it's an `@Override` and that test case extends `CamelTestSupport` which does some of the setup, like calling `createRouteBuilder`. Before you get too confused about this, read http://camel.apache.org/camel-test.html and http://camel.apache.org/testing.html

Answer (score 1):

A good way to make software better testable (especially software that communicates to external stuff) is to use dependency injection. I love [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice) and it is [directly supported by camel](http://camel.apache.org/guice.html).
(all this stuff will burden you with learning about dependency injection but it will pay very soon i can assure you)

In this scenario you would just inject "Endpoint"s. You pre-configure the endpoints like this (would be placed in "module").

```
@Provides
@Named("FileEndpoint")
private Endpoint fromFileEndpoint() {
    FileEndpoint fileEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("file:" + somFolder, FileEndpoint.class);
    fileEndpoint.setMove(".done");
    fileEndpoint.setRecursive(true);
    fileEndpoint.setDoneFileName(FtpRoutes.DONE_FILE_NAME);
    ...
    return fileEndpoint;
}
```

Your RouteBuilder just inject the endpoint:

```
@Inject
private MyRoutes(@Named("FileEndpoint") final Endpoint fileEndpoint) {
    this.fileEndpoint = fileEndpoint;
}
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(fileEndpoint)....
}
```

To easily test such an route you inject another endpoint for test not FileEndpoint but "direct:something". A very easy way to do this is ["Jukito"](https://code.google.com/p/jukito/), it combines Guice with [Mockito](https://github.com/mockito/mockito). A test would look like this:

```
@RunWith(JukitoRunner.class)
public class OcsFtpTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    public static class TestModule extends JukitoModule {
        @Override
        protected void configureTest() {
            bind(CamelContext.class).to(DefaultCamelContext.class).in(TestSingleton.class);
        }
        @Provides
        @Named("FileEndpoint")
        private Endpoint testEndpoint() {
            DirectEndpoint fileEndpoint = getContext().getEndpoint("direct:a", DirectEndpoint.class);
        return fileEndpoint;
        }
    }
    @Inject
    private MyRoutes testObject;

   @Test
   ....
}
```

Now the "testObject" will get the direct endpoint instead of the file endpoint.This works with all kinds of Endpoints and generally with all Interfaces/ abstract classes and Apis that heavily rely on Interfaces (camel excels here!).

Comment: I can not see getContext() function available in Module class. Could you please help me on this?

Comment: getContect() comes from "extends CamelTestSupport". This class prvides context and starts it (in tests). 
In my application i extend Camel's Main and override getContext. This returns an injected context. See https://github.com/dermoritz/camelExamples. it uses Weld but the thing with context is the same.