# Mock input queue in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

Hi I have application using apache camel and input queue that is a start point of the processing. I'm trying to find a nice way to mock somehow this input queue so :

- I reuse the production routing file, I don't want to copy and paste the contents and make just one change for the routing of the queue
- I can send the message to this 'mocked' queue and processing is done as in production

This is probably about changing 'queue:' into 'direct:' routing, but I couldn't find any other way than specifying another xml.

Comment: I have found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463356/how-to-mock-amqp-consumers-in-camel-testing/25505637#25505637

Comment: You can specity "queue:productuion_queue" as a property, `${start.endpoint}` and for your test specify `start.endpoint=direct:xyz`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Camels AdviceWith](https://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html) method to intercept messages during testing:

```
public class MySuperTest extends CamelTestSupport {
  public void testAdvised() throws Exception {
    // advice the first route using the inlined route builder
    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            // intercept sending to mock:foo and do something else
            interceptSendToEndpoint("mock:foo")
                    .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                    .to("log:foo")
                    .to("mock:advised");
        }
    });

    getMockEndpoint("mock:foo").expectedMessageCount(0);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:advised").expectedMessageCount(1);
    getMockEndpoint("mock:result").expectedMessageCount(1);

    template.sendBody("direct:start", "Hello World");

    assertMockEndpointsSatisfied();
  }

  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
    return new RouteBuilder() {
      @Override
      public void configure() {
        //TODO build your route here
        from("direct:start").process(...).to("mock:result");
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: How sending direct:start maps to mock:foo? I found this example before, but unfortunately it's not clear for me.

Comment: @czajek I added some more code. Might not run, I added this from memory without running it. It shows the `CamelTestSupport` and the use of a `RouteBuilder` inside the junit test.

Comment: I think I still don't get it. As I understand this helps me to mock the 'final' endpoint and this is something I have already achieved by using org.apache.camel.impl.InterceptSendToMockEndpointStrategy. From what I see here I still have processing from the 'input' endpoint which is a queue. That will result in some unexpected behaviour when there are some messages in the queue

Comment: I understand that above solution works if queue is somewhere in the middle of processing.

Comment: @czajek You can intercept from any endpoint. Does this answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can advise a route to replace your `from`-component, e.g. replace the `amq` endpoint with a `direct` endpoint. You can then use a producer template to trigger the route in your test.

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "/META-INF/spring/your-context.xml" })
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@MockEndpoints("none")
@UseAdviceWith
public class ReplaceFromTest {

    @Autowired
    protected CamelContext      context;

    @Produce(context = "your-camel-context-id")
    protected ProducerTemplate  template;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        AdviceWithRouteBuilder mockAmq = new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                replaceFromWith("direct:amq-mock");
            }
        };

        ((ModelCamelContext) context).getRouteDefinition("route_to_advise").adviceWith((ModelCamelContext) context, mockAmq);
        context.start();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        context.stop();
    }

    @DirtiesContext
    @Test
    public void sendMessageTest() {
        Map<String, Object> myHeaders = new HashMap<>();

        String myBody = "Some content";

        template.sendBodyAndHeaders("direct://amq-mock", myBody, myHeaders);

        // Verify the results
    }
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I have created class like this

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;

public class JmsToSedaComponent {

    private CamelContext camelContext;

    public JmsToSedaComponent(CamelContext camelContext) {
        this.camelContext = camelContext;

    }

    public void init() {
        camelContext.removeComponent("jms");
        camelContext.addComponent("jms", camelContext.getComponent("seda"));

    }

}
```

and then in the spring xml file:

```
    <bean class="com.lmig.ci.baods.dial.integration.JmsToSedaComponent" init-method="init">
        <constructor-arg ref="camelContext"/>
    </bean>
```

This replaces all JMS components to SEDA.